# Include JS files using function from other JS file in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying this stuff a lot but I am unable to get around with this stuff.
I have 2 JS files, add.js and console.js.

add.js

```
module.exports = {
    add: function add(a,b){
        return a+b;
    }
};
```

console.js

```
module.exports = {
    debug: function debug(a,b){
        console.log(add(a,b));
    }
};
```

A part of app.js code

app.js

```
var add = require('./add').add;
var debug = require('./console');
console.log(debug.debug(3,4));
```

This is throwing me an error in console. "add is not defined" referencing the add of console.log(add(a,b)) in console.js

So, in general is there a way where we can write all the requires in one place (in order) and the things work automatically. For example, we do the same in javascript.

```
<script src="add.js"/>
<script src="console.js"/>
```

And the thing works. But how to do the same stuff in Node JS.

Comment: Why would you need this? Simply require add.js where you are going to use it.

Comment: No actually that is just an example. I am just asking in general how to include the JS files which have functions from other JS files.

Comment: Consider it to be modules not files. You need a module. You ask to load it. The infrastructure itself will handle caching and such.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use add function in console.js file, you should require add.js file in console js file. Error says about add function which you have used in console.js file.